# Flutter, google_maps_flutter and webview_flutter are not match

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, maps

i have `webview_flutter: ^2.8.0` in my `pubspec.yaml` then i want to add `google_maps_flutter: ^1.2.0` package but it doesn't match, can it be fix? or what other package to replace google_maps_flutter: ^1.2.0 because this is my company project and webview_flutter: ^2.8.0 is already in the pubspec.yaml from the beginning and i cannot remove it of course.

> it shows something like this in output

```
Running "flutter pub get" in one-smile...                       
Because no versions of webview_flutter_platform_interface match >1.8.0 <1.8.1 and webview_flutter_platform_interface >=1.8.1 depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.1.0, webview_flutter_platform_interface >1.8.0 requires plugin_platform_interface ^2.1.0.
And because webview_flutter_platform_interface 1.8.0 depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0, webview_flutter_platform_interface >=1.8.0 requires plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0.
Because google_maps_flutter >=1.2.0 <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on google_maps_flutter_platform_interface ^1.2.0 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1, google_maps_flutter >=1.2.0 <2.0.0-nullsafety requires plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1.
Thus, google_maps_flutter >=1.2.0 <2.0.0-nullsafety is incompatible with webview_flutter_platform_interface >=1.8.0.
And because webview_flutter 2.8.0 depends on webview_flutter_platform_interface ^1.8.0 and no versions of webview_flutter match >2.8.0 <3.0.0, google_maps_flutter >=1.2.0 <2.0.0-nullsafety is incompatible with webview_flutter ^2.8.0.
So, because onesmile depends on both webview_flutter ^2.8.0 and google_maps_flutter ^1.2.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because onesmile depends on both webview_flutter ^2.8.0 and google_maps_flutter ^1.2.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

> and in debug console when i run it

```
Because no versions of webview_flutter_platform_interface match >1.8.0 <1.8.1 and webview_flutter_platform_interface >=1.8.1 depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.1.0, webview_flutter_platform_interface >1.8.0 requires plugin_platform_interface ^2.1.0.
And because webview_flutter_platform_interface 1.8.0 depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0, webview_flutter_platform_interface >=1.8.0 requires plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0.
Because google_maps_flutter >=1.2.0 <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on google_maps_flutter_platform_interface ^1.2.0 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1, google_maps_flutter >=1.2.0 <2.0.0-nullsafety requires plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1.
Thus, google_maps_flutter >=1.2.0 <2.0.0-nullsafety is incompatible with webview_flutter_platform_interface >=1.8.0.
And because webview_flutter 2.8.0 depends on webview_flutter_platform_interface ^1.8.0 and no versions of webview_flutter match >2.8.0 <3.0.0, google_maps_flutter >=1.2.0 <2.0.0-nullsafety is incompatible with webview_flutter ^2.8.0.
So, because onesmile depends on both webview_flutter ^2.8.0 and google_maps_flutter ^1.2.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because onesmile depends on both webview_flutter ^2.8.0 and google_maps_flutter ^1.2.0, version solving failed.)
```

Comment: you are using`webview_flutter: ^2.8.0` is nullsafe and your sdk may be 2.12.so you must use `google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1`.  This `google_maps_flutter: ^1.2.0` is not null version.so That is the reason described on the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see on pub.dev `webview_flutter: ^2.8.0` is nearly two months old uses latest api to interact with flutter.

[image]

**where your `google_maps_flutter: ^1.2.0` is quite old so update it to any of below versions and it should work.**

[image]